# How to do autocomplete for textfield of UIAlertController in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to do autocomplete for textfield, for example for the email.

I searched it in internet, I didn't find a version swift and a lot of demos use `tableview` to show the results.

My question is:

1 : I do not want use `tableview` to show the results, I want to do this like safari, when you write somethings, the result is gray and complete the sentence.

2 : I want do autocomplete for a textfield of `UIAlertController`. My code for the textfield of `UIAlertController` is

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter e-mail", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)

            let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.dismissKeyboard()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the textbox was added via storyboard.then click then text box

then choose AtrributeInspector -> change correction -> yes

this will use to work with autocorrect

Thanks,

Comment: textbox was added by  `ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way using Swift 5:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "...", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addTextField { (textfield) in
    textfield.text = "default value"
    textfield.autocorrectionType = .yes
}
```